# Could someone help tell what the labels are pointed out by red rectangles?

Tags: papers, perceptron

The following figure comes from the paper [The perceptron: A probabilistic model for information storage and organization in the brain](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.588.3775&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[image]

I can tell the labels pointed out by blue rectangles are: "Projection area", "A-units", "$R_1$", "inhibitory connections" and "$R_2$".

Could someone help tell what the labels are pointed out by red rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left-to right:

red: SENSORY RECEPTOR OR
blue: PROJECTION AREA

blue: A-UNITS

blue: R$_1$
red: BROKEN LINES SHOW
blue: INHIBITORY CONNECTIONS

blue: R$_2$